# The option '--poll' is not registered with the build command

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to rebuild my Angular 2 app using the CLI with this command:
`ng build -w --poll 100`

I am receiving this error in the console:

> The option '--poll' is not registered with the build command. Run `ng
>   build --help` for a list of supported options.

I am following the ng build documentation here:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Here is a snippet of my package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    ...
```

Why is this NOT working? Do I have to register poll with the build command for this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the most recent version of the CLI resolved this issue:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli